# Serving HTML, CSS and JS using Node.js and Express.js

Tags: html, css, node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express ();
app.use(express.json('public'))
app.get('/PKorn/zealtech', function(req, res)  {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/Ko.html'));

});

app.listen(4402);
```

when i using /PKorn is work with css but when i use /PKorn/zealtech work page but css is missing

Comment: Can you try to change `app.use(express.json('public'))` to `app.use(express.static('public'))` and change link in your html to `http://host:port/cssFileNameOrPathToCSSWithoutPublic/`

Comment: Cannot GET /web/ko show like this

Comment: Can you add your project directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `app.use(express.json('public'))` to `app.use(express.static('public'))`.

Comment: yeah i have been change but stail missing css